# Find an equation of a sphere if one of its diameters have endpoints...

Tags: calculus

I need to find an equation of the sphere if one of its diameters has endpoints $(3, 4, 6)$ and $(1, 2, 5)$.

I actually do not know how to even start this one. I usually struggle with problems that involve coming up with the equation. Would there be a certain formula to use that I can start off with?

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what happens for a *circle* with a diameter from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$.  The center $O$ (midpoint of the diameter) and radius $r$ are then given by

$O=(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2})$

$r^2=\dfrac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{4}+\dfrac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{4}$

Then the standard form equation is

$(x-\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2})^2+(y-\dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2})^2=\dfrac{(x_2-x_1)^2}{4}+\dfrac{(y_2-y_1)^2}{4}$

which can be rearranged to an expression involving differences of squares:

$((x-\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2})^2-(\dfrac{x_2-x_1}{2})^2)+((y-\dfrac{y_1+y_2}{2})^2-(\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{2})^2)=0$

And then factor each difference of squares as $u^2-v^2=(u+v)(u-v)$; you elegantly end up with this:

$\color{blue}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0}$

Now try it in three dimensions.  Each dimension operates independently 9f the others so we end up just adding on another product for the additional coordinates:

$\color{blue}{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)+(z-z_1)(z-z_2)=0}$

Answer (score 2):

Find the midpoint between those two points - there's your centre. Now find the distance between those two points - that's the length of the diameter (and half it for the length of the radius). From there you should have all the parameters you need for an equation of the form:

$$
(x-x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2
$$

where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the centre. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sort of. Could i use either endpoint as $x$ and $x_0$ in this case?

Comment: @CurlyFry what do you mean by that? To clarify, $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the variables of your equation and $x_0$ etc are components of the midpoint between your two endpoints.